# Laravel 8 - Unable to seed the DataBase / factory error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, tinker

Hi I am new to creating factories on Laravel and I am setting up a blog website.  I had this going just fine and now it isn't working anymore.

When I use "tinker" to add fake data using (`App/Models/Post::factory(30)->create();`), below error keep occurs. Could anyone please educate me why this error occurs?

```
App/Models/Post::factory(30)->create(); 
PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant App - assumed 'App' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in F:\coding\laravel\test-laraveleval()'d code on line 1 
PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant Models - assumed 'Models' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in F:\coding\laravel\test-laraveleval()'d code on line 1 
PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in F:\coding\laravel\test-laraveleval()'d code on line 1 
PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in F:\coding\laravel\test-laraveleval()'d code on line 1 
PHP Warning: Division by zero in F:\coding\laravel\test-laraveleval()'d code on line 1 
[!] Aliasing 'Post' to 'App\Models\Post' for this Tinker session. 
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'sint' for key 'categories_name_unique' (SQL: insert into categories (name, slug, updated_at, created_at) values (sint, ut-quisquam-et-et-tenetur-molestias-in-dolor-voluptatum, 2022-03-16 07:11:05, 2022-03-16 07:11:05))
```

'

Comment: In `php artisan tinker`, try either `Post::factory(30)->create()`, or `\App\Models\Post::factory(30)->create()`. If neither of those works, make sure you have a `Post.php` file within `app/Models`, with the namespace `namespace App\Models;`. Also, in the future, please include code for the Model in your question; it'll help us debug this faster.

Comment: You're using forward slash (  /  ) when you should be using back slash (  \  ). `App\Models\Post::factory(30)->create()`

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks. Next time I'll add the relevant codes also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define factory rules such that you have a constraint in your database that checks for category name uniqueness.

You should read how to write a custom factory in Laravel 8:[Examples how to generate factories](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#generating-factories).
[image]